# Providing assignments to variables from makefiles/kconfig

Tags: c, linux-kernel, makefile, linux-device-driver

I have an unsigned long which needs to get a platform specific variable.

I do not wish to use boot parameters as this driver will go into products and vendors are reluctant to change boot parameters.

I would like to know if this variable can be initialized from Makefile or from Kconfig.

I remember that the serial port address for early printk is provided in the Kconfig when I used the menuconfig long back to set it. But I never understood how that worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass that value from Kconfig file in that directory of the program file,
You can set the Kconfig to value of the variable which is needed.
Like for example, in the Kconfig, add below configuration for the variable

```
config  MY_VALUE_LONG          // config keyword
     hex "MY VALUE IS"         //What you see in the menuconfig
     default 0xAB123           //unsigned long value in hex
```

In the above Kconfig, **MY_VALUE_LONG** will hold you long value in the hex format, **MY VALUE IS** is what that will be displayed when $ make menuconfig is called, and the default value set using the **default** variable will be passed to the program.

In Program (where the variable value is required), use the config variable **CONFIG_MY_VALUE_LONG** to obtain the value in hexadecimal

Like for example,

> **unsigned long value  =  CONFIG_MY_VALUE_LONG**

Comment: Can I do it directly in Makefile? I am not using kconfig in some of my builds. I just hard code the makefile obj-y += module.o.

Comment: Can I pass decimals too in the same way?

Comment: Yes, you can int keyword instead of hex to pass value

Comment: Is there any changes for Makefile here?

Comment: No change required in Makefile

Comment: Its not working. Compilation says CONFIG_VAR undeclared. Can I use this in global scope?

Comment: is both the Kconfig and C file in the same directory

Comment: yes. but I am using a custome directory. drivers/my_drv/. Do I need to include my Kconfig in the  drivers/Kconfig or something like that?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59080/discussion-between-santosh-a-and-preetam).

Comment: Unable to connect to chat, the answer is Yes, you need to include in the driver/Kconfig

Comment: Thanks. That worked. Kinda strange that the Kconfig does not go through the makefile.

Answer (score 1):

Find the C file and Makefile implementation in below to meet your requirements

foo.c

```
 main ()
    {
        int a = MAKE_DEFINE;
        printf ("MAKE_DEFINE value:%d\n", a);
    }
```

Makefile

```
all:
    gcc -DMAKE_DEFINE=11 foo.c
```

MAKE_DEFINE is a define, which is enabled through Makefile

Comment: Thanks for the response, but can you kindly tell me how to put the same in a linux kernel makefile in a drivers directory